# Asus X540S laptop: internal microphone listed but not working

Tags: linux-mint, audio, pulseaudio, laptop, asus

The internal microphone is listed by the Sound tool of Linux Mint Cinnamon but I cannot use it in any way.

[image]

Also in `pavucontrol`:

[image]

Chances that the mic itself is faulty are negligible, it's a brand new Asus, and similar issues have been reported lately but without a solution -like [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=239855&p=1302531&hilit=mint+18+no+microphone#p1302531), also [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/895397/47206).

I hope I have more luck here.

```
 ~ $ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x81410000 irq 315
```

---

#### EDIT

in response to [dirkt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/193028/dirkt)'s comment:

- `alsamixer` shows this:

[image]

There is a MM to the right but not under PCM (isn't that the mic?).

- `amixer -c0 contents` gives [this (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/kE5sg4kp)
- I have tried to use with Skype and then tested with the 'Sound Recorder' tool, which only creates empty files. - Also I have tried `aplay /tmp/test-mic.wav` & `aplay /tmp/test-mic.wav` (like [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-test-microphone-with-audio-linux-sound-architecture-alsa)) to no effect.

---

#### Edit

in response to [dirkt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/193028/dirkt)'s second comment:

- the output of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` - [here](https://pastebin.com/qWE4cLwu).The laptop only has one audio jack (entry), for headphones, I do not have an external mic to test if that could work for mic too.

Comment: Have a look at `alsamixer` if there is anything muted (`MM` instead of `OO`) in the path of the mic which shouldn't be. If you can't find anything, please edit question with output of `amixer -c0 contents`. How did you try to use the mic?

Comment: @dirkt - I have updated the question in response to your answer.

Comment: You have controls for a "phantom" (internal) mic jack and a capture channel map, but curiously no other controls for capture/mic. Please put the output of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` in a pastebin. Note that if you are using `aplay` (speaker) or `arecord` (internal mic) to test, this will use the Pulseaudio compatibility layer, so make sure in `pavucontrol` you are using the right device (analog instead of digital etc.). `pavucontrol` will also show a VU meter for the mic (input tab).

Comment: @dirkt - I have solved it as indicated in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This might be an Asus-X540S-specific issue.)

I have solved it according to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/824806/47206

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
```

Then launch

```
hdajackretask
```

Then:

- Check 'Show unconnected pins'
- Check override pin 0x12 to internal mic.
- Apply and test.  Be sure that the mic level is high enough in sound settings (pavucontrol, etc)
- If it worked, select 'Install boot override'.

[image]

---

### UPDATE

In the Ubuntu 18.04-based Linux Mint 19, I had to check override pin **0x13** to internal mic **instead** of 0x12.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have enough reputation to comment, I will add this answer for others like myself. While this answer has been given before, what was left out is that there can be **multiple internal mics listed in alsamixer** and that **you have to mess with the volumes to find which one is your actual microphone**.

Comment: in the case in question there were **not** such multiple internal microphones listed in alsamixer (nor in pavucontrol)

Comment: If there are multiple internal mics listed, while your hardware only has a single mic, you are likely changing the wrong nodes with `hdajackretask` (or the BIOS already had wrong information).

Comment: @dirkt - the very specific setting involving `hdajackretask` worked for the Asus X540S laptop, where the internal microphone was listed in the sound setting but was nor recording input level. - In other cases the situation may be different (but then there is a different question): for example (as I tested in one case)  when the mic is NOT listed in`pavucontrol` under *Input Devices* tab, it may be because under *Configuration* tab, 'Analog Stereo Output' is selected instead of 'Analog Stereo Duplex'.